# MongoDB Aggregate Subtract Java Driver 3.3

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using the subtract operator as in the following shell query but can't figure out how to do the subtraction in Java.

```
db.deviceDetail.aggregate([
    {$match: {'accountId':23, 'status':'Stopped'}},
    {'$project': {
            'durationDiff': {'$subtract': [1479093620000, '$durationDate']},
            'stopStartDiff': {'$subtract': [1479093620000, '$stopStart']},
            'stopStart': 1,
            'durationDate': 1,
            '_id':0
        }
    },
    {'$match': {$or:[{'durationDiff': {'$gt': 0}}, {'stopStartDiff': {'$gt': 0}}]}}
 ])
```

The Java API seems to not support the subtract operator, so how should one define the durationDiff and stopStartDiff calculations below?

```
AggregateIterable<Document> rslt = coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                match(and(eq("assetName", "accountId"), eq("assetName", "accountId"))),
                project(fields(
                        excludeId(),
                        include(
                            "durationDiff", ...,
                            "stopStartDiff", ...,
                            "stopStart",
                            "durationDate"
                        )
                )),
                match(or(gt("durationDiff", 0), gt("stopStartDiff", 0)))
        ));
```

Sample document:

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("563064a4e4b0ea032ae14f77"),
    "accountId" : NumberLong(23),
    "stopStart" : NumberLong("1460133175000"),
    "status" : "Stopped",
    "durationDate" : NumberLong("1460133175000")
}
```

Comment: Can you pls provide sample document to test the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like for the simple use case you've. You will have to do the same for other variable. This will calculate the durationDiff.

For 2.x Version

```
BasicDBList values = new BasicDBList();
values.add(1479093620000L);
values.add("$durationDate");

AggregateIterable<Document> rslt = dbCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            project(fields(
                    excludeId(),
                    include(
                            "durationDiff",
                            "durationDate"
                    ),
                    new BasicDBObject("durationDiff", new BasicDBObject("$subtract", values))
                    )
            )
    ));
```

For 3.x Version

Using BsonDocument - Type Safe Version

```
BsonArray operands = new BsonArray();
operands.add(new BsonInt64(1479093620000L));
operands.add(new BsonString("$durationDate"));

BsonDocument subtract = new BsonDocument("$subtract", operands);


AggregateIterable<BsonDocument> rslt = dbCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        project(fields(
                excludeId(),
                include(
                        "durationDiff",
                        "durationDate"
                ),
                new BsonDocument("durationDiff", subtract)
                )
        )
));
```

Using Document - Non Type Safe Version

```
AggregateIterable<Document> rslt = dbCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        project(fields(
                excludeId(),
                include(
                        "durationDiff",
                        "durationDate"
                ),
                new Document("durationDiff", new Document("$subtract", Arrays.asList(1479093620000L, "$durationDate")))
                )
        )
));
```

Comment: Sorry didnt notice you were using 3.x driver. Updated to include the driver 3.x variant.